# How to fix Mint 16 Desktop crash/freeze after adding second toolbar and enabling/disabling monitor?

Tags: linux-mint

My operating system is Mint 16, forgot what flavor, probably KDE.  My desktop crashed after I connected a second monitor, added a second toolbar to the second monitor and then disable the monitor, and then rebooted. After I rebooted, my desktop is now frozen, with a fuzzy blank toolbar.

I forgot what the command is to open up the terminal outside of the desktop environment. The last time this happened to me, my friend explained to me that two desktops were running at the same time and a "watcher" program was disabling the second desktop environment while a "checker" was re-enabling the second desktop environment at the speed of the computer clock. My conky reports a 100% CPU usage, though I forgot to check the name of the top running programs. The power block was reporting 95 watts continuous.

How do I fix my Mint 16 Desktop crash/freeze after adding a second toolbar and enabling/disabling monitor?

Answer (score 1):

use `alt+control+F2` and `top` command then kill the process by its id !